# Formatted reference in LyX

Tags: cross-referencing, lyx

I am trying to insert cross-references so that whenever I refer to a lemma, proposition, theorem, etc. both the title "lemma" and its number are added automatically to the version. If I choose `Insert -> Cross Reference` and then choose `<reference>` in the reference format, the output only shows the number of the lemma itself, but then I have to write the word "lemma" manually. That's why I chose `Formatted reference` instead. I did this both to a lemma and the proposition. It worked fine with the lemma, but not with the proposition. What should I do?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Bumping this question. What should I write in the preamble if necessary?

Answer (score 1):

When using formatted reference, lyx loads `refstyle` package and checks if `\lemref` is defined via `\RS@ifundefined` which is provided by the `refstyle` package (this macro is similar to the current `\@ifundefined` from the latex kernel, but when the package was written they were a bit different).

If the command `\lemref` is not yet defined, its will be defined with `\newref{lem}{name=lemma~}`, if not, at the beginning of the document the command `\providecommand{\lemref}[1]{\ref{lem:#1}}` ill issue, which will define`\lemref{#1}` as `\ref{lem:#1}` if `\lemref` is not yet defined (which is how lyx utilizing cross references with  format).

For some reason it does so for lemma but not for proposition. For proposition it only does `\providecommand{\propref}[1]{\ref{prop:#1}}` at the beginning of the document. Since `\propref` is not defined at the beginning of the document, cross referencing a proposition will yield the  format.

You can issue a bug ticket [here](https://www.lyx.org/trac/wiki/BugTrackerHome) and ask the developers if this a bug.

**Conclusion**

You can do the same process as lyx does and write `\RS@ifundefined{propref}{\newref{prop}{name=proposition~}}{}` in the preamble, it should solve your problem.